# Changing value in dictionary, stored in SQLite database (Flask Python)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application that is using SQLite database. I have created this model to load data into the db

```
class Category(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    products = db.Column(db.Text)
```

This database has been populated with a lot of information, and I am trying to change a specific variable in a dictionary within the stored information.

```
# print 'products' for the first Category stored

x = Category.query.all()
xLoaded = json.loads(x[0].products)
print(xLoaded)

# output
[['test1', {'path': ['a', 'b', 'c']}], ['test2', {'path': ['d', 'e', 'f']}]]
```

Specifically, I am trying to change `'b'` in `'test1'` so I tried this:

```
x = Category.query.all()
xLoaded = json.loads(x[0].products)
xLoaded[0][1]['path'][1] = 'z'

db.session.commit()
```

However, this fails to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code only changes the value of the variable `xLoaded` not the `x`.

Change the value of variable `x`

```py
x = Category.query.all()
xLoaded = json.loads(x[0].products)
xLoaded[0][1]['path'][1] = 'z'
x[0].products = xLoaded

db.session.commit()
```